# Ошибка после компиляции python кода в pyinstaller, помогите

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller

Я скомпилировал код на python на pyinstaller, но после компиляции программа зависает и спустя время выдает ошибку. Все ничего, только сам код работает правильно, но после компиляции ошибка. Помогите пожалуйста(

Версия python = 3.10
Версия pyinstaller = 5.13.2

Вот что выдает программа после сбоя.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1103, in emit
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1103, in emit
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1103, in emit
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1103, in emit
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1103, in emit
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "logging\__init__.py", line 1103, in emit
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

И эта ошибка повторяется очень много раз.